# How to mutate an object in a array if it has the same key using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

Kindly help me to mutate the object in javascript. Lets say I have a below list of object, I want to objects if the keys are same in the first list Key "FOREFOOT - OUTER" repeated twice, value of this key different, in the first occurrence left is true and in the second occurrence right is true, I want this to be merges as `"forefoot - outer" : {left: true, right: true}`

```
[
    {
        "FOREFOOT - OUTER": {
            "left": true,
            "right": false
        }
    },
    {
        "FOREFOOT": {
            "left": false,
            "right": true
        }
    },
    {
        "FOREFOOT - INNER": {
            "left": false,
            "right": true
        }
    },
    {
        "FOREFOOT - OUTER": {
            "left": false,
            "right": true
        }
    },     
]
```

Expected answer is

```
[
    {
        "FOREFOOT": {
            "left": false,
            "right": true
        }
    },
    {
        "FOREFOOT - INNER": {
            "left": false,
            "right": true
        }
    },
    {
        "FOREFOOT - OUTER": {
            "left": true,
            "right": true
        }
    },
   
]
```

Can anyone please help me to find a solution for this in javascript ES6.

Comment: What have you written so far? Where are you stuck in your attempt?

Answer (score 1):

You could do a little function like this :

```
const filterArray = (arrayToFilter) => {
    const newArray = arrayToFilter;
    let i = -1;
    while (++i < newArray.length - 1) {
        // So we brows the array since the start finally.
        j = i;
        while (++j < newArray.length) {
            // We create a string to could use it in our if
            const item_i = Object.keys(newArray[i]) + '';
            const item_j = Object.keys(newArray[j]) + '';

            // If the 2nd occure is true, then we put the 1st true
            if (item_i == item_j) {
                if (newArray[j][item_j].left)
                    newArray[i][item_i].left = true;
                if (newArray[j][item_j].right)
                    newArray[i][item_i].right = true;
                newArray.splice(j, 1);
                // Seeing that we delete an element, we decrease our J
                j--;
            }
        }
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

So this is in order to merges only "true" value. Because in your sample you merges only True value. If you want merges false too, edit the if with :

```
if (item_i == item_j) {
    newArray[i][item_i].left = newArray[j][item_j].left;
    newArray[i][item_i].right = newArray[j][item_j].right;
    newArray.splice(j, 1);
    j--;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Codaid, But, the return value not gives the expected result. eg. The expected answer should be like below
{
        "FOREFOOT - OUTER": {
            "left": true,
            "right": true
        }
    },

Comment: Sorry, I should have added a new answer when I read your comment, but I was offered to edit instead of add a new answer by stackoverflow.